# How can I do an assignment of the condition (a query) if is true, or do another assignment if the condition is false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I save myself from typing

```
TypeOfVoyagePortActivity.find_by_description(activity_description)
```

twice?

This is the context I am using it in:

```
 if TypeOfVoyagePortActivity.find_by_description(activity_description)
   pl.activity = TypeOfVoyagePortActivity.find_by_description(activity_description)
 else
   pl.activity = TypeOfVoyagePortActivity.find_by_description("Custom") 
 end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
model = TypeOfVoyagePortActivity
pl.activity = model.find_by_description(activity_description) ||
  model.find_by_description("Custom")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could assign result of `find_by_description` to a variable

```
 if t = TypeOfVoyagePortActivity.find_by_description(activity_description)
   pl.activity = t
 else
   pl.activity = TypeOfVoyagePortActivity.find_by_description("Custom") 
 end
```

Or as a better alternative:

```
p1.activity = [activity_description, "Custom"].each_with_object(nil) do |a, memo|
  memo ||= TypeOfVoyagePortActivity.find_by_description(a)
end
```

Comment: with your second version, wont you consider to stop iteration on first positive result?

Comment: yeah, I was just thinking how to do it better :)

Comment: `inject([]) { |f,c| break if f.any?; ... }` ? :)

Comment: note that the second snippet is in some extension libraries (i.e. Facets) abstracted as `Enumerable#map_detect` (but not using `each_with_object`, a loop that breaks is more efficient). A pity that the core methods of `Enumerable` lack such a basic method. `[activity_description, "Custom"].map_detect { |d| TypeOfVoyagePortActivity.find_by_description(d) }`.